# VS2019 MSI Installer error 2727 after migration from packages.config to PackageReference

Tags: installation, windows-installer, visual-studio-2019, failed-installation, packagereference

I have a console application running on .NET Framework 4.7.1 in Visual Studio 2019 with a Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project (MSI Installer).

After migrating from **packages.config** to **PackageReference**, the `.msi` installer returns the following error once it collects all installer inputs and begins the install.

> The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2727.

`.msi` installer created before the migration works fine.  The executable and project work fine after the migration.  The problem is only with the installer.  The problem can be reproduced when installing from the VS 2019 project and from the generated `.msi` file.

There is an error in the Windows Event Viewer and the installer log:

**Event Viewer on remote machine**

```
Product: XXXXX -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2727. The arguments are: _0024F16DE39F4B7D9BF184AC802A7310, ,

- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="MsiInstaller" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">10005</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-10-21T19:14:41.779642800Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>18270804</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>XXXXXX.com</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-3296303954-3414968290-1573956784-1136" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Product: XXXXXX -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2727. The arguments are: _0024F16DE39F4B7D9BF184AC802A7310, ,</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Binary>7B41433031463831372D434435302D343530332D423239342D3844334438453538323844417D</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

**MSI Installer Log on local machine**

```
MSI (c) (4C:5C) [16:58:07:070]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLLEVEL property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (4C:5C) [16:58:07:070]: Note: 1: 2727 2: _7F06229DCDB74690AC0D18DBD0357B3B 
DEBUG: Error 2727:  The directory entry '_7F06229DCDB74690AC0D18DBD0357B3B' does not exist in the Directory table
DEBUG: Error 2835:  The control ErrorIcon was not found on dialog ErrorDialog
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2835. The arguments are: ErrorIcon, ErrorDialog, 
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2727. The arguments are: _7F06229DCDB74690AC0D18DBD0357B3B, , 
MSI (c) (4C:5C) [16:58:08:457]: Product: XXXXX -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2727. The arguments are: _7F06229DCDB74690AC0D18DBD0357B3B, ,
```

Nothing else in the log has the value `_7F06229DCDB74690AC0D18DBD0357B3B`.  This value is the same between installs.  This is not the `ProductCode` or the `UpgradeCode` in the installer properties.

#### Setup

- Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise
- Windows console project (runs as a service)
- .NET Framework 4.7.1
- Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project 1.0.0 extension
- Installer runs on Windows 10 Pro and Windows Server 2016

#### What I tried:

- Clean and rebuild everything
- Manually create all directories the installer is supposed to create
- Removed unused dependencies (dlls) from the installer - they were highlighted in red.
- Added `<SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>` to `*.csproj` file as suggested by another SO answer

All code is backed up so I can go back to `package.config` but would prefer not to do so unless no solution could be found.

**Note:**  for whatever reason, the `.msi` after the migration is almost twice as large as the `.msi` before migration.

#### Update

The installer fails right before the **Select Installation Folder** dialog (which is not shown when the failure occurs).

This is the screen before which the installer fails.
[image: This is the screen before which the installer fails.]

I also tried to revert the branch to before the migration but the revert is not working as the migration changes remain and prevent the installer from working.  I had to delete all files and restore them from Git to finally remove the migrated packages and get the installer working.

Comment: Are there some steps to reproduce your issue? Did you do something on setup project when migrating to PackageReference?

Comment: I did not change the setup project at all.  I did notice that the setup project ended up with more dependency dlls than the main project.  Excluding them after the error did not help.

Comment: Not sure how to reproduce the issue with a minimal example.  It happens right after the installer runs through the installer dialog (user inputs) regardless of what the inputs are.

Comment: It seems you finally chose to roll back to use packages.config? I tried to reproduce but the installer worked well on my side. I guess something affected the installer project while migrating to PackageReference. Perhaps you could also ask the author of this installer extension [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects&ssr=false#qna)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being to delete the old installer project, migrate to **PackageReference**, and create a new installer project.

Based on Git, the only differences ended up being the references in the `.vdproj` file.  The new installer was larger than the first but everything else was the same.

### Problem

Installer stops working after After migrating from **packages.config** to **PackageReference**.

### Solution

1. Delete the installer project (make sure you have a backup).
2. Do the migration.
3. Create a new installer project.

### Cause

Auto-migration does not update the **.dll references** in the **Installer** project.

Answer (score 1):

@eglease did most of the work here as I also  would say this happened right after a ProjectReferences conversion.

But **I found that I could clear the output and re-add it rather than deleting the whole project** that I was also able to clear the error.

Delete these (or maybe just the primary output)

[image]

Re-add them:

[image]

That cleared the error for me.

Comment: Great idea!  I don't remember if I tried this or not but it's good to know for the future.